# Add my sales together based on Id and Name using SUM function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created a request with SSMS:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(LastName,' ', FirstName) AS [Nom du vendeur], 
    SalesPersonID, 
    DATEPART(YYYY, [OrderDate]) AS [Annee], 
    FORMAT(SUM(soh.SubTotal), '#,#00.') AS [Ventes]
FROM 
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh 
INNER JOIN 
    Person.Person AS pp ON soh.SalesPersonID = pp.BusinessEntityID
WHERE 
    pp.PersonType = 'SP' 
    AND soh.OnlineOrderFlag = '0' 
    AND OrderDate NOT BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2011', 101) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '12/31/2011', 101) 
GROUP BY 
    SubTotal, OrderDate, SalesPersonID,LastName, FirstName
ORDER BY  
    [Annee], [Nom du vendeur]
```

And here is my output:

[image]

As you can see in the `[ventes]` column which represent the sales column, the sales don't add up depending on the Id number and Name but I do use the `SUM()` function in my select. Any ideas as to what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Remove subtotal from group by.

Comment: Learn to debug your own code. First, we don't know how you determined that "sales don't all add up". So provide an example of the values in your resultset, the total you expect, and how you calculated that total. Next, you should first order your rows using the same set of columns that you use for grouping. That way you can see the grouping of your rows and can more easily validate the sum. Next, you group by OrderDate but you only include the year in your resultset. That will likely make your validation more difficult since you will get a sum per day, not per year.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your `group by`:

1. You don't want to `group by` `SubTotal` when you are summing that column.
2. And you don't want to `group by` `OrderDate` when you are trying to sum the totals over a year. Rather you want to `group by` the same computation you are selecting e.g. `DATEPART(YYYY, [OrderDate])`.

So your corrected `group by` is:

```
GROUP BY DATEPART(YYYY, [OrderDate]), SalesPersonID, LastName, FirstName
```

FYI: If you post your questions in a format similar to the following, which is a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you make it much easier and much more likely for people to assist.

```
declare @SalesOrderHeader table (id int, SalesPersonID int, OrderDate datetime, SubTotal money, OnlineOrderFlag varchar(1))
declare @Person table (id int, FirstName varchar(64), LastName varchar(64), BusinessEntityID int, PersonType varchar(2))

insert into @Person (id, BusinessEntityID, FirstName, LastName)
  select 1, 1, 'Amy', 'Alberts' union all
  select 2, 2, 'Pamela', 'Ansman-Wolfe'

insert into @SalesOrderHeader (SalesPersonID, OrderDate, SubTotal)
  select 1, '5 nov 2019', 12.34 union all
  select 1, '6 nov 2019', 34.56 union all
  select 2, '7 nov 2019', 78.90 union all
  select 2, '8 nov 2019', 43.21

SELECT 
  CONCAT(LastName,' ', FirstName) AS [Nom du vendeur] 
  , SalesPersonID 
  , DATEPART(YYYY, [OrderDate]) AS [Annee] 
  , FORMAT(SUM(soh.SubTotal), '#,#00.') AS [Ventes]
FROM @SalesOrderHeader AS soh 
INNER JOIN @Person AS pp ON soh.SalesPersonID = pp.BusinessEntityID
--WHERE 
--    pp.PersonType = 'SP' 
--    AND soh.OnlineOrderFlag = '0' 
--    AND OrderDate NOT BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2011', 101) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '12/31/2011', 101) 
-- GROUP BY SubTotal, OrderDate, SalesPersonID,LastName, FirstName
GROUP BY DATEPART(YYYY, [OrderDate]), SalesPersonID, LastName, FirstName
ORDER BY [Annee], [Nom du vendeur]
```

Returns:

```
Nom du vendeur      | SalesPersonID | Annee | Ventes
----------------------------------------------------
Alberts Amy         | 1             | 2019  | 47
Ansman-Wolfe Pamela | 2             | 2019  | 122
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments,

remove subtotal from the group by clause,
aggregated values don't need to be in the group by clause.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, that what I did but it didn't change the result unfortunatly.