# Stored procedure passing multiple parameters with conditional results not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create this stored procedure but it's not working as expected, so when I pass parameters into it I'm not getting results back.

Here is my stored procedure, which is returning results:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP 100 *
    FROM [Test].[dbo].[Order] WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE [Deleted] = 0
      AND ([Id] = @OrderId OR @OrderId = 0)
      AND ([StoreId] = @StoreId OR @StoreId = 0)
      AND ([WarehouseId] = @WarehouseId OR @WarehouseId = 0)
      // if I insert payment status and statement here no results are returned
      AND [CreatedOnUtc] >= ISNULL(@CreatedFromUtc, '1/1/1900')
      AND [CreatedOnUtc] < ISNULL(@CreatedToUtc, '1/1/2999')
END
```

If I add this after the warehouseid and statement it stops returning results:

```
AND ([PaymentStatusId] = @PaymentStatusId OR @PaymentStatusId = 0)
```

Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: One would presume it is because there are no records that match all of those criteria.

Comment: @avery_larry If zero is passed as the parameter that part of the query should be ignored

Comment: @chrisc I suggest you build up a working example that you can use to demonstrate problems to us that way we can copy and paste your code and reproduce the exact problem. As it is we can't see the data in your table nor the datatypes. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58721555/1127428) of how you can do that using table variables. And you can test the contents of the SP as T-SQL without it being inside a SP.

Comment: The one would presume zero isn't being passed to @PaymentStatusId.  You'll need to show us the actual proc so we can see the declarations and then show us how you are calling/running the proc.  Are there any errors?

Comment: @DaleK it's fixed now, by mistake I was sending null. Will make sure I use sql profiler from now on to check data value.

Comment: @chrisc - my comment still stands for any future questions, They make them much easier to answer, and the easier you make it the more likely someone will assist.

Comment: @DaleK thanks for the heads up, I will do that in future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its safe use `coalesce()` function to include those `null` values.

```
  and iif(@PaymentStatusId = 0, 1, coalesce([PaymentStatusId], 0)) 
    = iif(@PaymentStatusId = 0, 1, @PaymentStatusId)
```

Comment: THanks @Metal but it's still not returning any results

Comment: @chrisc, how do you declare your @PaymentStatusId?

Comment: Like this ```@PaymentStatusId int = 0,```

Comment: Oh @Metal sql profiler is showing me it's null ```@PaymentStatusId=NULL``` in my code I was setting it to null. ```(paymentStatusId.HasValue) ? (object)paymentStatusId : DBNull.Value``` changed ```DBNull.Value``` to ```0``` and it's now working.
You were very helpful and right, it was a data issue. Thanks again for your help :)